# How to get environment variables into Ansible script run by cloud-init?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, ansible, cloud-init

I have a cloud-init bash script that pulls a zip from S3, unzips it, and then runs an Ansible playbook contained in it. Now, I also have environment variables baked into `/etc/environment`, and the Ansible playbook uses `lookup('env')` to grab those values. It works fine when run through bash, either as the main user or as root. But when it fires via cloud-init, the variables are not transferred through.

In my bash script, the first line is `source /etc/environment`, and I can echo them out just fine. It's only when the Ansible playbook does the `lookup` that it fails. Interestingly, I can force the variables as so:

`FOO=$FOO BAR=$BAR ansible-playbook -c local ...`

and that works. Does anyone have any idea how I can get around having to hardcode the variables into the playbook line, and just have them work as expected, i.e. pull from `/etc/environment`?

Edit: here's the cloud-init:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /etc/environment
doit() {
  aws s3 cp s3://my/scripts/dev-s3-push.tar.gz /tmp/my.tar.gz
  mkdir -p /app/deploy
  tar -C /app/deploy -zxvf /tmp/my.tar.gz
  cd /app/deploy
  FOO=$FOO BAR=$BAR ansible-playbook -i "localhost," -c local run.yml
}
doit
```

This is added into the User Data section in AWS.

Comment: Can you share your cloud-init script?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR, I've added it above. Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you put the `source` inside the `doit`? (I'm thinking it's an `export` issue.)

Comment: @JeffY: Unfortunately that didn't work. Within `doit`, I can do `echo $FOO` and get the proper value - it's only the Ansible playbook that can't read in the env vars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out. `lookup()` uses `os.getenv` underneath, and I found a few other questions related to `os.getenv` not returning properly.

The issue is that in my `/etc/environment`, i had it as `FOO=bar`, where it should have been `export FOO=bar`. Changing all the values over to that makes it work. I still have the `source` line in the cloud-init function, but I think this is solved now.